# The value of the rational "Möbius"-like transformations at infinity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, differential-geometry, mobius-transformation

If $\mathbb F$ is some field, the group $PSL(2, \mathbb F)$ consists of the mappings
$$
 x \mapsto \frac{ax + b}{cx + d}
$$
with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb F$ and $ad - bc = 1$. These mappings are defined over the extended field $\mathbb F_{\infty} := \mathbb F \cup \{\infty\}$ (or the so called projective line). As for example written on [wikipedia:Möbius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) we have $f(\infty) = \infty$ if $c = 0$.

> But I am asking myself what happens with $f(\infty)$ if $c \ne 0$?

There is another way to view these mappings, consider $SL(2, \mathbb K)$, the group of matrices 
$$
 \begin{pmatrix} 
   a & b \\ c & d 
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
with $ad - bc = 1$. Then each such matrix could be mapped onto such a mapping as above, and this correspondence is surjective. By computation we find
$$
 \frac{a\left( \frac{a'x + b'}{c' + d'} \right) + d}{c\left( \frac{a'x + b'}{c' + d'}\right) + d}
 = \frac{(aa' + c'b)z + (ab' + bd')}{(ca' + dc')z + (cb' + d'd)}
$$
and of course
$$
 \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} 
 \begin{pmatrix} a' & b' \\ c' & d' \end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix} aa' + bc' & ab' + bd' \\ a'c + dc' & cb' + dd'  
   \end{pmatrix}
$$
so this correspondence is a homomorphism. Such a mapping is the identity if $a = d, c = b = 0$, and the condition $ad = 1$ leaves the possiblities $a = b = \pm 1$, hence the kernel of this correspondence is
$$
 \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \quad
 \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
and this is precisely the center in the group $SL(2, \mathbb F)$. Hence $PSL(2, \mathbb F) \cong SL(2, \mathbb F) / Z(SL(2,\mathbb F))$. Now $SL(2, \mathbb F)$ acts on $\mathbb F^2$ in a natural way by matrix multiplication, hence we have an induced action of $PSL(2,\mathbb F)$ on $\mathbb F^2$. Now each $v = (x, y)^T\in \mathbb F^2$ could be identified with $(x/y, 1)^T$ if $y \ne 1$ and $(1,0)^T$ if $y = 0$, and by this we get an identification of $\mathbb F^2$ with $\mathbb F_{\infty}$ where $(1,0)^T$ corresponds to $\infty$. As
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}
   a & b \\ c & d 
 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ c \end{pmatrix}
$$
I guess we would have $f(\infty) = a/c$ if $c \ne 0$ (which corresponds to the projective point $(a,c)^T \equiv (a/c, 1)^T$). But I am not sure if this is reasonable, so I am asking what is $f(\infty)$ in the general case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(\infty)$ is $\frac{a}{c}$, as you say. Intuitively, plugging in $\infty$ takes the leading terms of the numerator and denominator. Formally it's what you wrote.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Nice that this just gets formally provable if we switch to the other interpretation as an induced action on matrix groups. So just one question: Imagine an analysis prof introducing Möbius transformations as functions, and then a student ask my question (without knowing the matrix repr.),what could the professor say without doing some handwaving and intuition about $\infty$,as then the student point to similar intuitive reasoning with limes operations that fail (there are enough examples where $\infty/\infty$ could give anything).So can the prof respond without using matrices?

Comment: @Stefan: if you restrict your attention to the case of $\mathbb{C}$, you can take a limit as $x \to \infty$ on the Riemann sphere. But I don't see any particular reason to avoid matrices (which work over any field, even when the concept of limits is unavailable).

Comment: @Stefan: What you're doing when considering $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ is to consider the riemann sphere. If you want to avoid handwavey limits, you could try to describe the action of $f$ on the sphere itself - which might get a bit messy, but $\infty$ is a proper element of it at least.

Comment: I am new to this stuff, could you hint at what you mean by "describe the action of $f$ on the sphere itself"; as you wrote $\mathbb C \cup \{\infty\}$ is considered the sphere?

Comment: @Stefan: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere. This is another name for the projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1$ over the complex numbers.